# Return a row for each time increment if it does not exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datepart

I have a query that returns the amount of jobs received per 15 minutes increments of everyday for a year. The problem is that it only returns data for each of the 15 minute increments if a job was received in that timeframe. The succinct version of the query is:

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(MONTH, Datim) AS Month#,
DATEPART(DAY, Datim) AS Day#,
(DATEPART(HOUR, Datim) + 1) AS Hour#,
((DATEPART(MINUTE, Datim) / 15) + 1) AS Interval#,
COUNT(JobNumber) AS TotalJobs

FROM Table

WHERE (Datim >= '2020-01-01' AND  Datim <= '2021-01-01')

GROUP BY
DATEPART(MONTH, Datim),
DATEPART(DAY, Datim),
(DATEPART(HOUR, Datim) + 1),
((DATEPART(MINUTE, Datim) / 15) + 1)

ORDER BY
DATEPART(MONTH, Datim),
(DATEPART(DAY, Datim) + 0),
(DATEPART(HOUR, Datim) + 1),
((DATEPART(MINUTE, Datim) / 15) + 1)
```

This is currently the output that is getting returned:

| Month# | Day# | Hour# | Interval# | TotalJobs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 456 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 789 |

I would like the data output to fill in a 0 for the TotalJobs field for each of the 15 minute increments as well as hours if they do not exist. The final output would look like this:

| Month# | Day# | Hour# | Interval# | TotalJobs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 456 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 789 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 0 |

Any ideas on what might be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can join with a [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) to get incremental numbers. Be aware that January alone will give you `31 days * 24 hours * 4 intervals = 2976 rows`, which might not be _the_ most user friendly overview :-)

Comment: Thanks @Sander! I will look into this method. The expected output I am looking for would have ```12 months * 31 days * 24 hours * 4 intervals = 35715 rows```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution with a [tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) table.

**Sample data**

Move your current query to a subquery or common table expression (CTE) so you can do a left join with it. Here, I just recreated the result rows from your current query.

```
create table AvailableData
(
  Month int,
  Day int,
  Hour int,
  Interval int,
  TotalJobs int
);

insert into AvailableData (Month, Day, Hour, Interval, TotalJobs) values
(1, 1, 1, 3, 123),
(1, 1, 2, 4, 456),
(1, 1, 4, 1, 789);
```

**Solution**

Gives you the first two months of 2021. Update the CTE's `Tally` and `Intervals` to get more incremental numbers and more months.

```
with Tally (n) as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM       (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n) -- 10^1 = 10
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n) -- 10^2 = 100
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n) -- 10^3 = 1000
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n) -- 10^4 = 10000
),
Intervals as
(
  select top (2*31*24*4) -- increase as required, max determined by Tally, example for 2 months
       --t.n,
       --dateadd(day, (t.n-1)/(24*4), '2021-01-01')                   as [Date],
         datepart(month, dateadd(day,  (t.n-1)/(24*4), '2021-01-01')) as [Month],
         datepart(day,   dateadd(day,  (t.n-1)/(24*4), '2021-01-01')) as [Day],
         (((t.n-1) % (24*4)))/4 +1                                    as [Hour],
         ( (t.n-1) %     4 )    +1                                    as [Interval]
  from Tally t
)
select i.Month,
       i.Day,
       i.Hour,
       i.Interval,
       coalesce(ad.TotalJobs, 0) as TotalJobs
from Intervals i
left join AvailableData ad
  on  ad.Month = i.Month
  and ad.Day = i.Day
  and ad.Hour = i.Hour
  and ad.Interval = i.Interval;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62da5c37c2672f4bdfb05d2281837d47) with some intermediate results.

---

**Full solution**

Quick merge and edit for the full year of 2021. Not validated.

```
with Tally (n) as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (      VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n) -- 10^1 = 10
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n) -- 10^2 = 100
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n) -- 10^3 = 1000
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n) -- 10^4 = 10000
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e(n) -- 10^5 = 100000
),
Intervals as
(
  select top (365*24*4) -- full year of 2021
         datepart(month, dateadd(day,  (t.n-1)/(24*4), '2021-01-01')) as [Month],
         datepart(day,   dateadd(day,  (t.n-1)/(24*4), '2021-01-01')) as [Day],
         (((t.n-1) % (24*4)))/4 +1                                    as [Hour],
         ( (t.n-1) %     4 )    +1                                    as [Interval]
  from Tally t
),
AvailableData as
(
  SELECT 
  DATEPART(MONTH, Datim) AS [Month],
  DATEPART(DAY, Datim) AS [Day],
  (DATEPART(HOUR, Datim) + 1) AS [Hour],
  ((DATEPART(MINUTE, Datim) / 15) + 1) AS [Interval],
  COUNT(JobNumber) AS TotalJobs
  
  FROM Table
  
  WHERE (Datim >= '2020-01-01' AND  Datim <= '2021-01-01')
  
  GROUP BY
  DATEPART(MONTH, Datim),
  DATEPART(DAY, Datim),
  (DATEPART(HOUR, Datim) + 1),
  ((DATEPART(MINUTE, Datim) / 15) + 1)
)
select i.Month,
       i.Day,
       i.Hour,
       i.Interval,
       coalesce(ad.TotalJobs, 0) as TotalJobs
from Intervals i
left join AvailableData ad
  on  ad.Month = i.Month
  and ad.Day = i.Day
  and ad.Hour = i.Hour
  and ad.Interval = i.Interval
order by i.Month,
         i.Day,
         i.Hour,
         i.Interval;
```

Comment: Good to see Itzik's tally function here for once instead of silly rCTE. He has a [new article](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) on it. Upvoted

Comment: Thanks again @Sander! This query looks really close to what I wanted but it doesn't appear to be incrementing the month and day correctly. Is it an issue in the Intervals section?

Comment: You are correct, that factor `31*` should not be there (I started with the 31 days from January). Answer and fiddle have been updated. The "fully merged" version now uses a factor `365` to get to a full year. This should produce 35040 rows (`365 days * 24 hours * 4 intervals`).

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate all of the help on this one @Sander! I just want to make a quick note that I wanted the results for 2020 which was a leap year so I kept the ```select top (12*31*24*4) ``` to accommodate the extra day.